# AWS: How to get AWS KMS Key ID based on Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I want to fetch the AWS KMS Keys ID based on tags assigned to them. I gone through AWS documentation but no luck.

Could someone help me out to get this thing resolved using AWS CLI?

Comment: List all keys and then filter on the client, there is no built-in method afaik.

Comment: List keys does not contains tags to filter.. I am doing this for automation purpose which should be able to handle

Comment: Yes, that is why you need to "List all keys and then filter on the client".

Comment: When list all keys don't have tags, then how can I filter using tags anywhere in client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after checking multiple documentation, I came to know that there is an api called `resourcegroupstaggingapi` in AWS to filter the resources based on tags if no native solution available . Below CLI command works well for my requirement.

**Solution:**

`aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-west-2 --resource-type-filters kms --tag-filters Key=Environment,Values=Dev`

Comment: That's a clever way around the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `list_keys()`, then loop through each key and call `list_resource_tags()`.

Comment: I would not recommend doing it via the AWS CLI unless you are quite adept at shell scripts. It would be easier in a scripting language like Python.

Comment: I am using ansible for automation and I think I am good with shell script well it works for me